# Generate a matrix of the sum of column values and sum of rows in new column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Generate a matrix of the sum of column values and sum of rows in new column in pyspark dataframe

```
colors = spark.createDataFrame([("Red","Re",20),("Blue","Bl",30),("Green","Gr",50)]).toDF("Colors","Prefix","Value")

    +------+------+-----+
    |Colors|Prefix|Value|
    +------+------+-----+
    |   Red|    Re|   20|
    |  Blue|    Bl|   30|
    | Green|    Gr|   50|
    +------+------+-----+

piv = colors.groupby("Colors").pivot("Prefix").sum("Value").fillna(0)

piv.withColumn("total",sum(piv[col] for col in piv.columns[1:])).show()

    +------+---+---+---+-----+
    |Colors| Bl| Gr| Re|total|
    +------+---+---+---+-----+
    | Green|  0| 50|  0|   50|
    |  Blue| 30|  0|  0|   30|
    |   Red|  0|  0| 20|   20|
    +------+---+---+---+-----+
```

Expecting even sum of columns like below (Expected dynamic code like if it has more columns and rows)

```
        Re  Bl  Gr  TOTAL
Red     20  0   0   20
Blue    0   30  0   30
Green   0   0   50  50
TOTAL   20  30  50  100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way. I have used `map` for doing sum over all the columns.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = colors.groupby("Colors").pivot("Prefix").sum("Value").fillna(0)

cols = df.columns[1:]

df.union(df.agg(f.lit('Total').alias('Color'), *[f.sum(f.col(c)).alias(c) for c in cols])) \
  .withColumn("Total", sum(f.col(c) for c in cols)) \
  .show()


+------+---+---+---+-----+
|Colors| Bl| Gr| Re|Total|
+------+---+---+---+-----+
| Green|  0| 50|  0|   50|
|  Blue| 30|  0|  0|   30|
|   Red|  0|  0| 20|   20|
| Total| 30| 50| 20|  100|
+------+---+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: A generator comprehension would be more readable `(F.sum(F.col(c)).alias(c) for c in cols)` and consistent with the generator comprehension in `sum()`